# How can I access nested nullable values of a Pydantic object without duplication?

Tags: python, pydantic

I receive a structure like this from an API:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Country(BaseModel):
    code: Optional[str] = None

class Address(BaseModel):
    street: str
    country: Optional[Country] = None

class Person(BaseModel):
    firstName: str
    lastName: str
    address: Optional[Address] = None
```

If I want to get the country code, I need to do this:

```
def get_country_code(p: Person):
    if p.address and p.adress.country:
        return p.address.country.code
    return None
```

As you can see, I need to duplicate `p.address` 3 times when I have a depth of 3. In my actual case the data is even more nested.

This is super annoying and makes the code harder to read. I wish there was something like this:

```
def get_country_code(p: Person):
    return p.?address.?country.code
```

The `?` in front of the attribute access essentially means "if the following attribute exists, take it. If not, return `None`"

### Possible Solution #1: Convert to dict

If it was a dictionary, I could at least do this:

```
def get_country_code(p: Person):
    return p.get("address", {}).get("country", {}).get("code", None)
```

Hence I'm currently thinking about just converting it back to a dictionary... which is kind of sad. Is there a better way to access the nested attributes?

### Possible Solution #2: Dict default values + Modify BaseModel

I could change the `Optional[Address]` to `Union[Address, Dict[str, Any]]` and make the default an empty dictionary. However, a Pydantic BaseModel does not have `.get(some_str)`. Hence I would need to modify it.

### Question

I cannot change the fact that the data structure is so heavily nested or that there are some many nullable fields. I just have to accept that.

Is there a way to have the `.get("attribute", "fallback")` syntax without loosing the editor/mypy support?

Comment: What you wish existed (`p.?address.?country.code`) does exist. It's called `getattr`.

Comment: @Shinratensei Oh, right, I completely forgot about that  However, I still lose mypy / editor support when I use getattr.

Comment: Hmmm well you can always `cast()` the result to `Optional[str]`

Answer (score 2):

I usually just use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr). It's not exactly pretty, but it does the job

```
return getattr(getattr(p.address, 'country', None), 'code', None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on [@Matias Cicero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69349067/5472354), if your data structure is as heavily nested as you say, maybe something like this becomes more readable. But I would even guess that some neat library alreardy contains a method to iteratively apply the same function like this.

```py
attrs = ["address", "country", "code"]

def get_country_code(p: Person):
    i = 0
    while p := getattr(p, attrs[i], None) and i < len(attrs):
        i += 1
    return p
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use third party modules, I'd recommend using [pydash](https://pydash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```py
import pydash as _

...

def get_country_code(p: Person):
    return _.get(p, 'address.country.code')
```